# Sharepoint Online and PowerApp

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a PowerApp that captures information on a SharePoint 365/Online list.
I want to publish a link to the app on the homepage of the SharePoint site.  But the link should open the app in the 'view' where you add a new item.  In other words, when you click on the link, it opens the app with blank entries, to complete the form.  Is this possible and how do I create that type of link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using something termed as deep-linking, which allows you to read parameter from URL query string. You can then read the query string inside power app using `Param()` function. On a SharePoint page you can have a link with URL set as

`https://apps.powerapps.com/play/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx?view=new`

You can read the query string using `Param()` function and create a formula as below.

`If(Param('view')='new',Navigate('formname');NewForm('formname'))`